# Confidence Interval for $2\theta^{-2}x$

Tags: probability, statistics

For a sample size of one from the population with distribution:

$f(x; \theta)=2\theta^{-2}x$  for $0<x<\theta$

Find a $100(1-\alpha)\%$ Confidence Interval for $\theta$.

Anytime I see $\theta$, I feel like the pivot method is probably the way to go, but any help would be taken.

Comment: *the pivot method*? Good grief... What about coming back to the definition? Let $I$ denote an interval. What does it mean that $I$ is a confidence interval with probability $p$ for $\theta$ based on one observation $X=x$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For any value of $\theta$, the probability must be at most $\alpha$ that the confidence interval for the observed value does not contain $\theta$. That can be achieved in different ways. For instance, we can require that only the lowest $x$ values lead to a confidence interval not containing $\theta$:

$$
\int_0^b2\theta^{-2}x\,\mathrm dx=\theta^{-2}b^2\stackrel!=\alpha\;,
$$

which yields $b=\sqrt\alpha\theta$ as the upper bound of $x$ values for which $\theta$ lies outside the interval, leading to the confidence interval $[x,x/\sqrt\alpha]$. Alternatively, we can require that only the highest values of $x$ lead to a confidence interval not containing $\theta$:

$$
\int_c^\theta2\theta^{-2}x\mathrm dx=1-\theta^{-2}c^2\stackrel!=\alpha
$$

yielding $c=\sqrt{1-\alpha}$ and thus the confidence interval $[x/\sqrt{1-\alpha},\infty]$. Of course we could also use anything in between, e.g. a fraction $\alpha/2$ of the highest and a fraction $\alpha/2$ of the lowest $x$ values, yielding $b=\sqrt{\alpha/2}\theta$ and $c=\sqrt{1-\alpha/2}\theta$ and the confidence interval $[x/\sqrt{1-\alpha/2},x/\sqrt{\alpha/2}]$.